# Is there a tape drive connected?

Tags: opensuse, scsi, tape

I need to know if there is a SCSI tape drive connected to my OpenSUSE Linux server. I tried checking the status of `/dev/st0` but got an error message:

```
mt: /dev/st0: Input/output error.
```

`/proc/scsi/scsi` contains the following entries:

```
Attached devices:
    Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
      Vendor: hp  Model: DVD RW AD-7586H  Rev: KP03
      Type:   CD-ROM              ANSI SCSI revision: 05
    Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 05 Lun: 00
      Vendor: HP  Model: C7438A  Rev: ZP8B
      Type: Sequential-Access     ANSI SCSI revision: 03
```

`lsscsi` output:

```
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       DVD RW AD-7586H  KP03  /dev/sr0

[2:0:5:0]    tape    HP       C7438A           ZP8B  /dev/st0
```

Comment: What does `lsscsi` produce? (You may need to install `lsscsi`.) Alternatively, what does `cat /sys/block/st0/device/{type,model,vendor}` output?

Comment: usm:/proc/scsi # cat scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: hp       Model: DVD RW AD-7586H  Rev: KP03
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 05 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: C7438A           Rev: ZP8B
  Type:   Sequential-Access                ANSI SCSI revision: 03

Comment: i couldn't find Neither St0 Nor Device directory in /sys/lock path

Comment: Don't reply with the output of commands in comments.  It presents as almost-unreadable gibberish.  Instead, **edit your post** and add the requested info to your question.  Use the `{}` icon in the editor to format it as code / program output.

Answer (score 4):

Your HP C4738A drive is a DDS-5 tape drive, so you do have a tape drive in your server. You might get more details on the cause of the error you're getting from `mt` by looking at the output of `dmesg`. The [HP Linux Tape Tools](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/storage-software/product-detail.html?oid=406729) will probably come in handy...

Answer (score 0):

You can search sysfs for the device name and check if "scsi_tape" is in the path:

```
find /sys/devices -name "nst[0-9]" | grep scsi_tape
```

On my system this yields:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.2/0000:20:04.0/0000:25:00.0/0000:26:08.0/host15/target15:0:1/15:0:1:0/scsi_tape/nst0
```